# Save image as base64 in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express

I looking for the best way to upload an image from mobile phone to my server. I am currently using html5 to open the camera and take the picture, then I convert the file into a base64 string, then I send to the server, then save it in MongoDB.
I am expecting around 1000 to 1500 user request per day ( upload image ) , so I have the following question :

1. Is it a good way to do it?
2. Should I compress the base64, if yes how?
3. Should use a specific server to handle this task?

My backend is node express and the front end is ReactJS.

Thanks

Comment: It's usually better to store files such as images in Amazon S3 or saved directly to the filesystem. Just store metadata about the images (such as their S3 link) in the database.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your situation. Reading and writing images from a `cdn` via i.e. streams is usually faster than reading and writing binary representations of images i.e. `base64` from a database. However, your speed if reading from a `cdn` will obviously be effected by what service you use. Today, companies like Amazon can offer storage to a very cheap price so if you are not building a hobby app for like a student project you can usually afford it. Storing binary representation of images actually end up a little bit bigger in size than storing the image itself. You don't compress the `base64`, you compress the image before converting it. However, if you can't afford a storage account and if you know your users won't upload that many images it is usually enough to store binary representations of the images in a database. Mongo Atlas, for example, offers 512 mb for free on their database clusters. Dividing tasks of your app such as database requests and `cdn` services from your main application is usually a good choice if possible. This way you will divide the cpu, memory, etc. of your hardware and it will lead to faster reading and writing tasks for the user.

There are a lot of different modules for doing this in `node`. [JIMP](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) is a pretty nice one with loads of built in functions like resizing images and converting them to binary, either as `Buffer` or `base64`.

Comment: Thanks. My main goal here is that user does not wait too long for the image to upload. I am expecting 1000 or 1500 image to be uploaded in one day, but it is only a one-day event the rest of the year the app is closed. I do like the idea of compressing the file and then convert it to base64, any clue on how to do it?

Comment: Yes. [JIMP](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) is a nice module with loads of built in functions like resizing images and converting them to binary, either as `Buffer` or `base64`. Will update my answer